# Unable to validate my self generated certificates using nginx

Tags: ssl-certificate, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm facing a crazy issue while trying to set up a reverse proxy using Nginx.

I created a Win server 2022 and added the Certificates autority feature.
I got my CA and installed it in my root certificate storage
I generated few certificates for remote server and they are working correctly.
I also generated a webserver certificate for a intraweb server (using openssl)

I exposed the URL using a Nginx reverse proxy (config file below)

> server {
> listen 443 ssl http2;
> listen [::]:443;
> server_name my_web.local_network;
> ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/my_web_certificate.crt;
> ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/my_web.key;
> ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
> ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
> access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
> error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;
> location / {
> proxy_pass         http://localhost:3001;
> proxy_http_version 1.1;
> proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
> proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
> proxy_set_header   Host $host;
> }
> }

I checked my nginx configuration, everything seems OK.

But whenever I try to access my website using the url specified, I get an error message saying my Root certificate Autority is unknown.

I checked and tried to reimport the certificate by following instructions from this page
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/valid-root-ca-certificates-untrusted
Same issue.
This is the exact message I get from my browser
https://my_web.local_network/dashboard

L’autorité de délivrance du certificat du pair n’est pas reconnue.
Aka : SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

HTTP Strict Transport Security : false

HTTP Public Key Pinning : false

I imported the RCA on my server and added to the root certificate folder using update-ca-certificates.
The RCA is correctly shown when do a cat /etc/ca-certiifcates.conf
But I keep having the same error message.

Does anyone has an idea abouth what I should try to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance,
Ary